# Substitute expression in conditional expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can do something like this:

```
["val1" if some_method() == True
    else "val2" if some_method() == False
    else "val3"]
```

This works, however I have to call `some_method()` multiple times. I could do this, of course:

```
m = some_method()
["val1" if m == True
    else "val2" if m == False
    else "val3"]
```

But now I have m declared for the rest of the code.
Is there a better way to do this? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
[with some_method() as m:
    "val1" if m == True
    else "val2" if m == False
    else "val3"]
```

Comment: The entire point of booleans is that they have *two* states – ``True`` *or* ``False``. Mixing in a third or even more states defeats the point of boolean logic. That these ``if`` expressions are hard to write should not motivate you to add more logic to them, but to go for a completely different approach.

Comment: That's not what I want to do. True/False was supposed to be an easy example to explain what I want to do. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does your `some_method()` return, `True`, `False`, *or* some other kind of result that is not a boolean? Sounds like a poor design…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't natively support switch statements or `let` blocks, both of which would solve your variable scoping problem directly. But we can always approximate the construct with lambdas.

```
[(lambda m: "val1" if m == True else "val2" if m == False else "val3")(some_method())]
```

But at that point, you probably want to ask yourself whether it's better to throw this chunk of logic into its own aptly-named function

```
def some_method_val():
  m = some_method()
  return "val1" if m == True else "val2" if m == False else "val3"

[some_method_val()]
```

Then `m` only exists for the duration of the function call, not for the whole program, and the function name, if chosen well, can serve as convenient documentation of *why* you were doing this dispatching thing with Booleans.

Answer (score 2):

[Python 3.9 optimized this idiom](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations):

```
["val1" if m == True
    else "val2" if m == False
    else "val3"
 for m in [some_method()]]
```

Or if the method's result is hashable:

```
[{True: "val1", False: "val2"}.get(some_method(), "val3")]
```